# How to read data from Bigquery into Shiny App made with Golem

Tags: r, shiny, bigrquery, golem

I am trying to read data from a Bigquery table into a Shiny App following Golem's framework.

This can be easily done by adding the following code before the `ui` and `server` functions in an `App.R` file

```
bq_auth(path = "xxxxxxxxxxxx.json") # authenticating biqrquery with service account json file

# Establishing connection
con <- dbConnect(
           bigrquery::bigquery(),
           project = "project id",
           dataset = "dataset name",
           billing = "project id"
)
```

But I am a little bit lost on how is the way to do it when using `Golem`.

Following this [thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-developer-series-episode-2-follow-up-thread-colin-fay-on-golem-and-effective-shiny-development-methods/32618/6) I created a `reactiveValue()` on the `app_server.R` file.

```
#' The application server-side
#' 
#' @param input,output,session Internal parameters for {shiny}. 
#'     DO NOT REMOVE.
#' @import shiny
#' @import bigrquery  
#' @noRd

app_server <- function( input, output, session ) {
# Your application server logic 
bq <- reactiveValues()

observe({

    bq$con <- dbConnect(drv = bigquery(),
                    project = "project_id",
                    dataset = "datset_id",
                    billing = "project_id")

})

}
```

I also imported `bigrquery` but this has seem to broke something as now I get the following errors when I run `run_dev.R`:

```
> golem::document_and_reload()
Loading Dashboard
Error : object ‘DBI’ is not exported by 'namespace:bigrquery'
-- Error documenting your package ----------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> # Run the application
> run_app()
Error in run_app() : could not find function "run_app"
```

Comment: Hey, the error on "could not find function run_app()" usually means that the document_and_reload() function has failed. Could you paste here the whole output of running the run_dev.R script please?

Comment: I edited my question to include the errors I get when running `run_dev.R`. Maybe also interesting to mention is that, even when  I undid the changes that end up in the error, `run_dev.R` is still giving the same error. Thanks for taking the time to look at thsi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the issue, based on your error:

```
> golem::document_and_reload()
Loading Dashboard
Error : object ‘DBI’ is not exported by 'namespace:bigrquery'
-- Error documenting your package --
```

Somewhere in your code, you're trying to call bigrquery::DBI(), but it's not a function from this package. Hence the error with `{golem}`: you can't load everything if you have a namespace error :)

You should either find this code error in :

- in one of your R Scripts where you do `bigrquery::DBI()`
- in your NAMESPACE where you might have `importFrom(bigrquery, DBI)`
- in your @importFrom in your RScript, where you might be doing `@importFrom bigrquery DBI`

Removing this should solve the issue.

Cheers,
Colin

Comment: Thanks for the  quick response, I did made the mistake of writing at some point `@importFrom bigrquery DBI`  in one of my modules but then corrected it but I was still having the same error. I had to manually edit the NAMESPACE file, now it works again.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Indeed `{roxygen2}` can sometime forget to remove elements from the NAMESPACE, so sometimes it's worth deleting it and re-run `devtools::document()` just to be sure :)